# Flag a row to row duplicates in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below

df:

```
Contaract_ID      Date                      value
123               2011-10-02 07:18:16       250
128               2015-12-06 07:13:18       200
123               2011-10-02 07:18:16       250
123               2011-10-02 07:18:16       250
```

From the above I want to create a new column which tells the given row is row to row duplicates or not.

Note: First row among duplicates should not be flagged as duplicates.

Expected Output:

```
Contaract_ID      Date                      value     Duplicate
123               2011-10-02 07:18:16       250       No
128               2015-12-06 07:13:18       200       No
123               2011-10-02 07:18:16       250       Yes
123               2011-10-02 07:18:16       250       Yes
128               2016-12-06 07:13:18       210       No
128               2016-12-06 07:13:18       210       Yes
```

I tried below code but that does not solve.

```
df['duplicate'] = df.duplicated(keep=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need `yes` for all dupes without first duplicated row with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with default `first` parameter and [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['duplicate'] = np.where(df.duplicated(), 'yes', 'no')

print (df)
    ontaract_ID      Date  value duplicate
123  2011-10-02  07:18:16    250        no
128  2015-12-06  07:13:18    200        no
123  2011-10-02  07:18:16    250       yes
123  2011-10-02  07:18:16    250       yes
128  2016-12-06  07:13:18    210        no
128  2016-12-06  07:13:18    210       yes
```